# Data from database in 2 php files

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 2 PHP files. 1 of them is the file that runs most of the PHP code, the other one shows the HTML page.

I would like to show some database information on my second PHP page (with includes some HTML). The problem is, I doesn't show any data.

I tried using `print_r()` on the database results but those only show on the first page.

Let me explain myself with my code:

1st PHP page (test.php)

```
// Class Initialization, DB connection etc.
require_once 'core/init.php';

// Create instance of class Subscription
$s = new Subscription();

// Get results from the DB
$sInfo = $s->get(Session::get('user'));
$sInfo = $s->data();

// When print_r() is ran here it shows the DB results
print_r($sInfo);

// Include the second PHP file
require_once VIEW_ROOT . '/general/test_view.php';
```

2nd PHP page (test_view.php)

```
// Header file
<?php require_once VIEW_ROOT . '/templates/header.php'; ?>

// Main content
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        // Checking if the DB information is an array, "is not array" is shown
        <?php if(is_array($sInfo)): ?>
        <p>Is array!</p>
        <?php else: ?>
        <p>Is not array</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>

// Footer file
<?php require_once VIEW_ROOT . '/templates/footer.php'; ?>
```

My question, why does it not receive data on the second page?

Comment: do you get anything from `test_view.php` displayed?

Comment: Yes, it displays the page as it should, only "is not array" is shown, while it should be "is array!"

Comment: anything conflicting in your `header.php`?

Comment: Are you sure $sInfo is an array? Whats the output of print_r($sInfo) in test.php?

Comment: `$sInfo = $s->get(Session::get('user'));
$sInfo = $s->data();` ~ the second expression overwrites thr first

Comment: @RST Thanks for mentioning that. Apparently my colleague made `$sInfo` in the header. That's why it was conflicting! Thanks a bunch!